# Partial order question, is reflexivity implied

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question whether below sets of relationship are partial order?

```
a≤b, b≤c, c≤d
```

I wonder whether reflexivity is implied or not. What would you answer to above question, without any extra information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if reflexivity was implied, transitivity is not true for that relation. Of course, transivity might also be implied, then you got a linear ordering of 4 elements.

Answering "no" would be the best idea, IMO, because without further info, it's best not to assume anything.

Comment: How trasitivity is violated? Should it be explicitly specified like a≤d for above set to be partial order?

Comment: Exactly.  It's the same 'omission' as with $a \le a$, etc.